# ReactJS/CSS: How to set div height based on other element height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to set an fixed height to a div, to force the overflow scroll. The problem is, I'm doing this with JavaScript, inside a useEffect hook, but it's not working well. Sometimes the height it's set well, but at the most times is wrong.

I created a function inside the component, then, call it inside a useEffect hook:

```
const TweetsPanel: React.FC<TweetsPanelType> = ({ tweetsData }) => {

  function setHeightTweetsDiv() {
    const height = document.getElementById('last-boicotes')?.clientHeight;
    // the "last-boicotes" div it's in another component, in the same page.
    document.getElementById('tweets-content').style.height = `${height}px`;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeightTweetsDiv();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h2>Tweets</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="tweets-content">
        // tweets
      </div>
    </>
);
```

Seems to work, but its setting the wrong height. After reload the page some times, it works:

[DevTools inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZOUf.png)

[Rendered code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJHtH.jpg)

I'm trying to fix the height to set a equal height. The left column will always be fully displayed, the right one, will always be bigger, so i need this one to be height fixed, the same height of the left, and the overflowed content will be scrollable.

I can't use flex-box, cause inside each column has an div to the heading and another to the content. And the div that I need to scroll it's inside the main column div.

[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gY7E.jpg)

If someone knows how to achieve this in some other way, please tell me.

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem setting a delay to call the function inside the useEffect hook:

```
setInterval(setHeightTweetsDiv, 1000);
```